# Problem with .htaccess on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

Yesterday I installed LAMP on my Ubuntu 10.04. At first everything seemed fine, but, when I launched my PHP app (I copied it from Windows 7, where I use XAMPP) it didn't accept my .htaccess file. So all of my URLs are broken at the moment.

What I did for .htaccess to work.

1.When I created separate config file in ./sites-available/ I changed Directory section `AllowOverride` from `None` to `All`

```
<Directory /some_path/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

2.Also the first line in my .htaccess file is `RewriteEngine On`.

Everything worked fine on Windows in XAMPP. When I launched http://localhost it gave me 500 Internal Server Error. When I change `AllowOverride` back to `None`, it opens index.html in my root folder and not index.php.

---

UPD: error.log says about error 500:

```
[Sat Jun 26 09:40:53 2010] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /some_path/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

---

Could anyone suggest any solution on how to fix it?

Comment: Check your `error.log` for what caused the 500 error.

Comment: Apparently, setting the [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive to `None` only prevents the symptom of your issue popping up: “When this directive is set to `None`, then .htaccess  files are completely ignored. In this case, the server will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem.”

Comment: @Pekka I updated the question information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message mod_rewrite hasn't been loaded. Activate it with `a2enmod rewrite` and restart your Apache httpd with `service apache2 restart`.

Comment: Great. Worked as a charm. But for those who will read this question and who are new to all of that it is better to add `sudo` before every command in this answer.

Comment: @Eugene - Only if you're not root ;)

Answer (score 1):

You seem not to have installed or activated `mod_rewrite` in your Apache installation. The line

```
Invalid command 'RewriteEngine'
```

is pretty clear. When you set `AllowOverride` to `none`, the `.htaccess` file will not be parsed at all, thus, no error message appears.

You would have to activate or install the `mod_rewrite` module.